# SpriteKit Game Losing FPS after main scene restart

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm creating a game using Sprite Kit, and I have an issue where the game slowly loses fps with every reiteration of the my main scene.

I've tried to use Xcode's Instruments, but have gotten no closer to the root of my issue.

> This is my function to end the game and present the Game Over Scene:

```
func endGame(){

    let endGameScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "EndGameScene" ) as! EndGameScene
    endGameScene.score = score




    //let transition = SKTransition.push(with: SKTransitionDirection.right, duration: 0.5)
    self.view?.presentScene(endGameScene)

    transitionNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.white, size: self.frame.size)
    transitionNode.zPosition = 5
    self.addChild(transitionNode)
    transitionNode.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.3))




    gameOver = true


}
```

> This is my function to present the Game Scene as a result of the
>   restart button being tapped:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first

    if let location = touch?.location(in: self) {
        let nodeArray = self.nodes(at: location)

        if(nodeArray.first?.name == "replayButton"){


            self.view?.presentScene(gameScene)

            transitionNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.white, size: self.frame.size)
            transitionNode.zPosition = 5
            self.addChild(transitionNode)
            transitionNode.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.3))
```

I also checked for leaks using instruments, but none come up. Similarly, the heaviest stack trace log shows no areas in my class file that took the most time, as shown here: (wasn't able to upload an image for some reason, so here's the link)

https://puu.sh/wtrMZ/1bb8c6542a.png

The game starts at a solid 60 fps, and then drops to 58, then to 57, then to 55, then to 54, and so on. I tried the **deinit {}** test, and the scene deallocates fine. I used the debugger to check my memory usage, and while it does go up ever so slightly, it barely breaks 50 mb in a single sitting. I also don't think it's a problem of removing unused nodes, because I make sure to remove them in every instance, but I could be wrong:

> deinit

```
deinit {

    self.removeAllChildren()
}
```

I am genuinely stumped, as I don't even know how to begin to fix this. Any help or constructive criticism is very much appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT:**

I never invalidated the two main timers in my Game Scene class. I simply invalidated them in my endGame function:

`func endGame(){

```
    let endGameScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "EndGameScene" ) as! EndGameScene
    endGameScene.score = score




    //let transition = SKTransition.push(with: SKTransitionDirection.right, duration: 0.5)
    self.view?.presentScene(endGameScene)

    transitionNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.white, size: self.frame.size)
    transitionNode.zPosition = 5
    self.addChild(transitionNode)
    transitionNode.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.3))

    pillarTimer.invalidate()
    durationTimer.invalidate()



    gameOver = true


}`
```

Fixed my issue perfectly.

Comment: You are not removing a thing, nada, nadie, when you re-present the scene.  Besides, don't do it through the game scene.  Let the view controller do it.

Comment: Could you provide some elaboration?